# Send a subtitle file (.VTT) with the mp4 from Node/Express to Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am using Node/Express to send an mp4 video to the frontend for which I am using angular. The video is being sent smoothly and everything's working perfectly. Now, I want to send the VTT file that contains the subtitles, along with the mp4. I do not know how to do that? I have tried searching but, couldn't find any help. Here's my code:

> Node/Express

```
router.get('/playVideo', (req, res) => {

const path = "videos/testVideo.mp4";
const pathSubtitle = "videos/testsub.vtt";

const stat = fs.statSync(path);
const fileSize = stat.size;

const head = {
  'Content-Length': fileSize,
  'Accept-Ranges' : 'bytes',
  'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
}

res.writeHead(200, head);
fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
});
```

> Angular

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<br>
<div class="jumbotron-fluid">

  <video id = "videoPlayer" controls preload = "metadata" style = "width: 
      65%; position: fixed; border: 2px solid #7c2c6c;">
      <source src="http://localhost:3000/playVideo" autoplay type = 
      "video/mp4">
  </video>
  
</div>
</div>
```

How can I attach the subtitle file with the video response? Or, link to any other documentation that explains that in detail?

Comment: On the angular part do you use a video tag? How does the frontend part look like?

Comment: @ste-xx, I have edited the code.

Comment: Just create a similar entry point for subtitles and add <track> into <video> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serve the vtt file on a different url (for example /playVideo.vtt) then use the track element to display it:*

```html
<video id = "videoPlayer" controls preload = "metadata" style = "width: 
      65%; position: fixed; border: 2px solid #7c2c6c;">
    <source src="http://localhost:3000/playVideo" autoplay type = 
      "video/mp4">
    <track default src="http://localhost:3000/playVideo.vtt">
</video>
```

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API#within_site_css and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track

*code has not been tested *yet*

Comment: That's not the issue. I don't know how to send the file from the backend. Do I have to send it as a blob from a separate endpoint? Can't I do the same using a single endpoint?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to serve them on the same endpoint, so you would need 2 endpoints.